# Spider scrapes data in scrapy shell but not in script

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I wrote a spider that scrapes ticket information from [this website](https://seatgeek.com/awolnation-tickets/) using code from another spider that works correctly (only needing to change the xpaths and the url. When I use the url in the terminal, I am able to access the response and extract different elements on the page from it. When I run the spider script, I get this error:

RLError: 
2015-07-11 14:12:31 [boto] ERROR: Unable to read instance data, giving up

and the spider closes basically right after opening without scraping any elements. I've tested all of the xpaths and they are correct and I even copied the url directly from the webpage. Is there something different about this site that doesn't allow it to be scraped or is there a problem with the code? Btw, the site that I was able to scrape data from had a url that ended with .html so maybe it is that only those kinds of sites can be scraped or something. Any help would be appreciated on this, thanks.

```
import sys
import re
import json
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider , Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Join, MapCompose
from seat_geeks_scraper.items import ComparatorItem
from urlparse import urljoin

bandname = raw_input("Enter a bandname \n")
sg_url = "http://www.seatgeeks.com/" + bandname + "-tickets"
class MySpider2(CrawlSpider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [416]
    name = 'comparator'
    allowed_domains = ["seatgeek.com"]
    start_urls = [sg_url]
    tickets_list_xpath = './/*[@itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"]'

    def parse_json2(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        listings_info = jsonresponse.get('listings')
        price_list = [i.get('pf') for i in ticket_info]
        ticketPrice = price_list[0]
        loader.add_value('ticketPrice', ticketPrice)
        return loader.load_item()

    def parse_price2(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        ticketsLink = loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
        json_id= ticketsLink.split('/')[6]
        json_url = "https://seatgeek.com/listings?client_id=MTY2MnwxMzgzMzIwMTU4&id=" + json_id + "&_wt=1&&_=1436364489501"
        yield scrapy.Request(json_url, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_json, dont_filter = True) 

    def parse2(self, response):
        """

        # """
        selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        # iterate over tickets
        for ticket in selector.select(self.tickets_list_xpath):
            loader = XPathItemLoader(ComparatorItem(), selector=ticket)
            # define loader
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()
            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader
            loader.add_xpath('eventName' , './/a[@class = "event-listing-title"]/span[@itemprop = "name"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventLocation' , './/a[@class = "event-listing-venue-link"]/span[@itemprop = "name"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('ticketsLink' , '//a[@class = "event-listing-button"]/@href')
            loader.add_xpath('eventDate' , '//div[@class = "event-listing-date"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventCity' , './/span[@itemprop  = "addressLocality"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventState' , './/span[@itemprop  = "addressRegion"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventCountry' , './/span[@itemprop  = "addressCountry"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventTime' , '//div[@class = "event-listing-time"]/text()')

            #ticketsURL = "concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets/" + bandname + "-" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            tickets_url = "www.seatgeek.com/" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            #ticketsURL = urljoin(response.url, ticketsURL)
            yield scrapy.Request(tickets_url, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_price2, dont_filter = True)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That `boto` error relate to AWS services, are you sure it's about the scraping? By the way, `allowed_domains` contains an extra / at the end, you should remove it. What does `scrapy crawl comparator2` stats at the end show?

Comment: @paultrmbrth Sorry for the late reply! I just updated the post with screenshots of the terminal after running the spider. I think that it has something to do with the extension of the url because I was just able to scrape another website with .html extension, but this one isn't working. And I took out the slash in the allowed domains. Thanks

Comment: Your site (seatgeek.com) is not a part of your allowed domains (www.seatgeek.com). Remove the 'www' prefix.

Comment: @JavierAyres It didn't work. I just updated the code in the post with what you said

Comment: I have the same issue. I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: should the value in `sg_url` have `"seatgeek.com"` instead of `"seatgeeks.com"`?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 I pip uninstalled boto and the error dissappeared, but it still crashes immediately. Can you comment out your `yield scrapy.Request` lines and let me know if it runs? It worked for me, so I can at least scrape the first page.

Comment: @tegancp I changed the url and the same thing happens.

Comment: @robert Even if I comment out the yield request line, the same thing happens. Also, why do you need to uninstall boto? What does it do?